# R / Twitter Live Streaming: Error: The stream disconnected prematurely

Tags: r, twitter, streaming, twitter-streaming-api

I would need to keep collecting tweets to live stream data and show insights in Power BI.

I have the following R code to stream tweets continuously. It tries to scrap tweets every 10 seconds. After first 10-14 times, it throws an error:

```
The stream disconnected prematurely. Reconnecting...
```

Below is the code:

```
q <- "maths"
streamtime <- 10 
filename <- "test.json"
rt <- stream_tweets(q = q, timeout = streamtime, file_name = filename)
```

How do I overcome this limitation?

Comment: If you are live streaming, why are you only connecting for 10 seconds at a time and then reconnecting? If you try to connect to Twitter too many times in quick succession then you will be throttled with a 420 error. Check [the Twitter documentation on this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/connecting).

Comment: @AndyPiper With the R package I use, I would have to specify the time frame I would need to stream the tweets. Is there any way that I dont specify it and directly stream?

Comment: It looks like the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/vignettes/stream.html) says you could run for hours if you wanted to. Either way, continually disconnecting and reconnecting will cause the Twitter API to throttle your connections as mentioned in the other link I shared.

Comment: Mine disconnects within minutes even when following documentation and setting the timeout to something like 600. If i stop running and restart the script, the stream starts again fine but then disconnects